# How to execute shell script from Python after passing input parameters

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a shell script in my JSON document `jsonStr` which I am able to execute it using Python subprocess module and it works fine.

Below is my Python script which works fine if I execute the shell script without passing anything -

```
import subprocess
import json

testing = "HelloWorld"

jsonStr = '{"script":"#!/bin/bash \\n STRING=\'Hello World\' \\n echo $STRING \\n"}'

j = json.loads(jsonStr)

print "start"
subprocess.call(j['script'], shell=True)
print "end"
```

Now is there any way to pass a variable value to my shell script in the json document from the Python script? Meaning I need to pass `testing` value to my shell script and then print out from the shell script the value of `testing` after getting executed from the subprocess module.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use this?

```
import subprocess
import json

testing = "HelloWorld"

jsonStr = '{"script":"#!/bin/bash \\n STRING=\'%VP%\' \\n echo $STRING \\n"}'.replace('%VP%', testing)

j = json.loads(jsonStr)

print "start"
subprocess.call(j['script'], shell=True)
print "end"
```

In the JSON you can a have placeholder and you can replace that placeholder instead of passing a Variable to the dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Like [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) say, supply environment variables to the subprocess in the `env` argument. Note that supplying the argument replaces the *entire* environment; you will need to supply the existing values if you want them available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you provide a simple example basis on my example? It will help me to understand better. I am little rusty in Python and bash scripting..

Comment: `subprocess.call('echo "$foo"', env={'foo': '42'}, shell=True)`

Comment: Sorry.. :( still not able to understand.. How I will use this in my Python code..

Comment: Can you help me here with a simple example which can help me understand better? I am sorry as my understanding is not that much with Python and subprocess module...

Comment: There is no example simpler than the one I gave you. I cannot think for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
    subprocess.call(j['script', str(var1), str(var2)], shell=True)
```

Comment: what is var1 and var2 here? Can you provide full example?

Comment: That's a comment not an answer.

Comment: @ssh subprocess.call(j['script' , testing], shell=True)

Comment: Throwing together random bits of syntax rarely has a correct (or even *coherent*) result.

Comment: @arun: and how my shell script will look like?